# Find relation level from text field

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a table containing geographical structure of units. There are parent-child relation columns but I want to use the existing text field (instead of recursion) to find the relation level between the items.

*(here's a table creation script)*

```
drop table if exists #temp_structure

create table #temp_structure
(org_id int,
parent_org_id int,
org_name nvarchar(255),
search_tree nvarchar(255))

insert into #temp_structure
values
(1,null,'World','| 1 |'),
(2,1,'Europe','| 1 | 2 |'),
(3,1,'North America','| 1 | 3 |'),
(4,1,'South America','| 1 | 4 |'),
(5,1,'Asia','| 1 | 5 |'),
(6,1,'Africa','| 1 | 6 |'),
(7,1,'Australia','| 1 | 7 |'),
(8,2,'Spain','| 1 | 2 | 8 |'),
(9,2,'Germany','| 1 | 2 | 9 |'),
(10,2,'Italy','| 1 | 2 | 10 |'),
(11,2,'France','| 1 | 2 | 11 |'),
(12,8,'Madrid ','| 1 | 2 | 8 | 12 |'),
(13,8,'Barcelona ','| 1 | 2 | 8 | 13 |'),
(14,9,'Berlin','| 1 | 2 | 9 | 14 |'),
(15,9,'Munich','| 1 | 2 | 9 | 15 |'),
(16,10,'Rome','| 1 | 2 | 10 | 16 |'),
(17,10,'Milano','| 1 | 2 | 10 | 17 |'),
(18,11,'Paris','| 1 | 2 | 11 | 18 |'),
(19,11,'Marseille','| 1 | 2 | 11 | 19 |')
```

The expected result I would like to achieve is presented below (I listed only one 4th level example):

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
| org_id | search_item | nest_level |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 |           1 |          1 |
|      2 |           2 |          1 |
|      2 |           1 |          2 |
|      3 |           3 |          1 |
|      3 |           1 |          2 |
|      4 |           4 |          1 |
|      4 |           1 |          2 |
|      5 |           5 |          1 |
|      5 |           1 |          2 |
|      6 |           6 |          1 |
|      6 |           1 |          2 |
|      7 |           7 |          1 |
|      7 |           1 |          2 |
|      8 |           8 |          1 |
|      8 |           2 |          2 |
|      8 |           1 |          3 |
|      9 |           9 |          1 |
|      9 |           2 |          2 |
|      9 |           1 |          3 |
|     10 |          10 |          1 |
|     10 |           2 |          2 |
|     10 |           1 |          3 |
|     11 |          11 |          1 |
|     11 |           2 |          2 |
|     11 |           1 |          3 |
|     12 |          12 |          1 |
|     12 |           8 |          2 |
|     12 |           2 |          3 |
|     12 |           1 |          4 |
.....................................
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

I was able to pull the org_id-search_item relation using STRING_SPLIT, but I still miss the tricky level part (I wonder about enumerating the '|' characters)

```
SELECT t.org_id
    --,substring(replace(search_tree, ' ', ''), 2, len(replace(search_tree, ' ', '')) - 2)
    ,ss.value as search_item
FROM #temp_structure t
CROSS APPLY string_split(substring(replace(search_tree, ' ', ''), 2, len(replace(search_tree, ' ', '')) - 2),'|') ss
```

Comment: It's two separate operations.  FIrst you need recursive CTE to calculate the levels.  Second, split (using an order preserving splitter like [Jeff Moden's](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) DelimittedSplitN4k) the search_tree into either a table with fk referencing back to the org_id or nested JSON (or XML).

Answer (score 0):

I have not thoroughly tested this, but you could try something like the following:

```
-- Table mock-up.
DECLARE @temp TABLE ( org_id int, parent_org_id int, org_name nvarchar(255), search_tree nvarchar(255) )

-- Insert sample data...
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
    (1,null,'World','| 1 |'),(2,1,'Europe','| 1 | 2 |'),
    (3,1,'North America','| 1 | 3 |'),(4,1,'South America','| 1 | 4 |'),
    (5,1,'Asia','| 1 | 5 |'),(6,1,'Africa','| 1 | 6 |'),
    (7,1,'Australia','| 1 | 7 |'),(8,2,'Spain','| 1 | 2 | 8 |'),
    (9,2,'Germany','| 1 | 2 | 9 |'),(10,2,'Italy','| 1 | 2 | 10 |'),
    (11,2,'France','| 1 | 2 | 11 |'),(12,8,'Madrid ','| 1 | 2 | 8 | 12 |');

-- Select data in a nested level...
SELECT
    org_id,
    search_item,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY org_id ORDER BY org_id, parent_org_id, search_item DESC ) AS nest_level
FROM @temp AS tmp
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST ( [value] AS INT ) AS search_item FROM STRING_SPLIT ( tmp.search_tree, '|' )
            WHERE NULLIF ( [value], '' ) IS NOT NULL
) AS tree
ORDER BY
    org_id, parent_org_id, search_item DESC;
```

Returns

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
| org_id | search_item | nest_level |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 |           1 |          1 |
|      2 |           2 |          1 |
|      2 |           1 |          2 |
|      3 |           3 |          1 |
|      3 |           1 |          2 |
|      4 |           4 |          1 |
|      4 |           1 |          2 |
|      5 |           5 |          1 |
|      5 |           1 |          2 |
|      6 |           6 |          1 |
|      6 |           1 |          2 |
|      7 |           7 |          1 |
|      7 |           1 |          2 |
|      8 |           8 |          1 |
|      8 |           2 |          2 |
|      8 |           1 |          3 |
|      9 |           9 |          1 |
|      9 |           2 |          2 |
|      9 |           1 |          3 |
|     10 |          10 |          1 |
|     10 |           2 |          2 |
|     10 |           1 |          3 |
|     11 |          11 |          1 |
|     11 |           2 |          2 |
|     11 |           1 |          3 |
|     12 |          12 |          1 |
|     12 |           8 |          2 |
|     12 |           2 |          3 |
|     12 |           1 |          4 |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```